# How to get a smaller brace?

Tags: braces, mathjax

This is my latex:

```
$$ \left\{\begin{align} e&=\lim_ { n → \infty } \left( 1 + \frac { 1 } { n } \right) ^ { n }  \\ \frac { 1 } { e }&=\lim_ { n → \infty } \left( 1 - \frac { 1 } { n } \right) ^ { n }  \end{align}\right. $$
```

[image]

But I don't like so big brace. I mean I hope get a smaller brace like the red one in following:

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: please show a full example, `align` is a top level environment, I don't see how you can use `\left\{` in that position without getting an error?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have fixed it

Comment: Use `\Biggl\{` and nothing on the right side.

Comment: No that is still just a fragment, if I try to make a document using that fragment I get `! Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;
(amsmath)                trying to recover with \`aligned'.`

Comment: also the arrow makes the warning `LaTeX Warning: Command \textrightarrow invalid in math mode on input line 6.` with pdflatex or `Missing character: There is no → (U+2192) in font cmr7!` with lualatex. What tex system are you using?

Comment: @Sigur Thanks very much. It work for me indeed

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about Mathjax, as noted OP in one oh his comment, and such id off topic here.

Comment: @Zarko As I understand it, MathJax is also belong to LaTeX??

Comment: @yode, mathjax tag description say: "MathJax is is an open source JavaScript display engine for mathematics that works in all modern browsers. It allows LaTeX commands as input which are then rendered similar to the way LaTeX itself does it. Note that questions dealing with installation of MathJax, how it works, or rendering problems are widely considered to be off topic and are at risk of being closed."

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
% \rule[offset]{width}{height}
\left\{\rule[-3ex]{0em}{6ex}\right.
\begin{aligned}
   e &= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}
        \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n  \\
   \frac{1}{e} &= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}
        \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)^n
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, It's seem this method don't work if I'm using Mathjax.

Comment: @yode mathjax does not use tex, so mathjax questions are mostly off topic here (This also explains how you can have a brace to the left of align, which isn't possible in latex.)

Comment: @yode this answer produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3mfi.png) using the mathjax test page linked from mathjax.org

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As I understand it, MathJax is also belong to LaTeX?

Comment: @yode not really, it emulates as subset of latex math markup but it doesn't use tex at all it is javascript. It is a good thing, but  as you found here it has significant differences with latex and it's just confusing to mix both systems at this site (there is a mathjax tag at stackoverflow that is actively monitored by the mathjax devlopers, or the mathjax help list at mathjax.org) Often you can phrase a question that coves both and can be asked here, but if you start with a question that has a latex syntax errror as in this question, it's hard to give a latex answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want a smaller left-hand curly brace, you should shrink the math expressions as well, e.g., by using `\tfrac` instead of `\frac`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
e&=\lim_ { n \to \infty } \left( 1 + \frac { 1 } { n } \right) ^ { n }  \\ 
\frac { 1 } { e }&=\lim_ { n \to \infty } \left( 1 - \frac { 1 } { n } \right) ^ { n }  
\end{aligned}
\right. 
\qquad\text{vs.}\qquad
\Bigg\{ % <-- NOT "\left\{"
\begin{aligned} 
e &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \bigl( 1 + \tfrac{1}{n} \bigr) ^ { n }  \\ 
\tfrac{1}{e} &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \bigl( 1 - \tfrac{1}{n} \bigr) ^ { n }  
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```